# ORA 0092 missing or invalid option while locking the users

Tags: oracle11g

I have to lock the users in the database based on certain criteria. I have pulled those records in to a temp table and using it in a cursor to lock the user accounts in oracle. 
I got the error as

> 0092 missing or invalid option

Can someone please help me to solve this issue.

```
FOR CUR_USERS (SELECT USERNAME FROM TMP_USUS)
LOOP
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER CUR_USERS.USERNAME ACCOUNT LOCK';
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

"In" is missing. Try below.

```
FOR CUR_USERS IN (SELECT USERNAME FROM TMP_USUS)

LOOP

BEGIN

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER CUR_USERS.USERNAME ACCOUNT LOCK';

END;

END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not replaced inside a string constants. So you are trying to lock an account name `CUR_USERS.USERNAME` over and over again. You need to concatenate the value into the string.

You are also missing the `in` for the cursor definition and additional `BEGIN` is unnecessary and the `END` and `END LOOP` are in the wrong order for that.

```
FOR CUR_USERS IN (SELECT USERNAME FROM TMP_USUS) LOOP
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER '||CUR_USERS.USERNAME||' ACCOUNT LOCK';
END LOOP;
```